# get image properties from windows explorer using C++

Tags: c++, windows, image, explorer

I am using C++ and would like to  get the image information from a jpeg/tiff/png/bmp file. Windows explorer shows the following properties and I would like to get them programatically.

[image]

Where do I get information on the programming interface for Windows explorer for these properties?

Comment: I would recommend an existing library for this kind of EXIF metadata, like [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Better to use external image manipulation library. Some examples are OpenCV,
GIL as part of Boost,
DevIL,
CImg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use GDI+, no need for any extra library. Windows already comes with it.

See what Microsoft says about doing so here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533832(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there any way to update the metadata similarly? I looked it up, but it requires me to use bitmap and bitmap needs to rewrite the whole image before it can save the resolution